# gentoo - Disable parallel build for llvm

Tags: memory, installation, gentoo, cmake, oom

I have Gentoo installed on computer with relatively small amount of RAM (1 GB). When I install `llvm` (`emerge -a llvm`), the computer always goes out of memory. All 4 `cc1plus` processes are using about 25 % of RAM when the system is unusable. I think using only one process at a time could help.

How can I run `llvm` build (uses `cmake` and `ninja`) with only one compiler process?

---

## Update

I had to make this change in `make.conf`:

```
#MAKEFLAGS="-j3"
MAKEFLAGS="-j1"
```

I was trying a lot of other variants but I will write in few days. (Because the compilation takes several hours and if there is no RAM available, I must reboot it by disconnecting power even I use swap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `ninja` isn’t `make`, its ebuild should recognize and respect any `-j` parameter specified in the `MAKEOPTS` environment variable. That means you should be able to force a maximum of one job via `MAKEOPTS=-j1`. You can do this on a one-time basis:

```
MAKEOPTS=-j1 emerge -a llvm
```

You can also set this change globally/permenantly for all packages on your system by editing the `MAKEOPTS=` line in `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

However, if you set `MAKEOPTS=-j1` via your shell or `make.conf`, the parallelization settings will be applied to all packages which `emerge` installs. If you want to apply it to just that one package, you can create the file called `/etc/portage/env/sys-devel/llvm` (create any missing directories if necessary) and place these contents in it:

```bash
MAKEOPTS=-j1
```

This will apply the variable only to the llvm package itself.

How to do this in the shell:

```
mkdir -p /etc/portage/env/sys-devel
echo MAKEOPTS=-j1>>/etc/portage/env/sys-devel/llvm
```

### Ninja and `MAKEOPTS`

In Gentoo, because people rely on `MAKEOPTS=-j«n»` to control the number of jobs, various eclasses and ebuilds will map this variable’s `-j` parameter to the equivalent for the acutal build system in use. You can see this in [`eclass/ninja-utils.eclass`](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/eclass/ninja-utils.eclass?id=ade171d2ed87156f92698c38f7531f2c4f358c94#n50) (which is used by `cmake-utils.eclass` which is used by `llvm`). That snippet extracts just the `-j` parameter and passes it to `ninja` because `ninja` supports that parameter while it might not support other things people place in `MAKEOPTS`.

*Disclaimer: I haven’t actually tested this with the latest `llvm` ebuild. Please comment if there are issues with this answer!*

Comment: See update of the answer. :-(

Comment: @jiwopene Ah, I see. So it looks like you were trying to use `MAKEFLAGS`, ended up accidentally calling it `MAKEFAGS` instead, and yet neither of those are supported envvars. It’s `MAKEOPTS` ;-)

Comment: I was compiling again, so I am going to stop it and retry.

Comment: It looks it is now OK.